# user_id in session not set when I decode the base64 cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:foo] = "bar"
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Email or password is invalid."
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

When I decode the base64 cookie, I get:

```
{I"session_id:EFI"%14cd484a34917f7d923ef8222c16e0e1;TI"foo;FI"bar;FI"_csrf_token;FI"1ajWlOZok1Amp8Nh9uOdUWzeM20b873zocEbyiR+b1ao=;FI"user_id;Fi }
```

How come the my `session[:foo]` is set but not my `session[:user_id]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that it is set, but the value of `user_id` is such that it's `Marshal.dump` output (which is what a cookie stores) is a non printable or whitespace character. If you're interested in why only `user_id` is affected in this way you'd have to look into the details of the marshal format (which doesn't appear to be widely documented). I'd guess that with integers ruby basically spits out the byte value(s), which will often result in unprintables.

I don't know how you're doing that base64 decode, but if you do it in a ruby console then the default output of inspect does show non printable characters

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the marshal.dump? yeah, there was some "?" black diamond char prior I paste in here... Would that explain?

Comment: `Marshal.dump` is a way of serialising ruby objects (which you can then load with `Marshal.load`, and is how session data is encoded. This serialised form is arbitrary binary data, which is why it's base64 encoded before being stored in the cookie. That unprintable character you removed probably was the user id

Comment: Just a last question, is the session cookie signed? meaning it can't be edited? If yes, how does it works? Oh and how come only the user id  was showing unprintable chars,do you have an idea?

Comment: What I'm really trying to say is what guarantee that the user won't be able to change the user_id in his session cookie?

Comment: Part of the cookie value before you decode it is a signature (separated from rest with -- I think)